# Run query on specific partition of partitioned MySQL table

Tags: ecto

I would like to run my `Ecto.Query.from` on a specific partition of a partitioned MySQL table.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE `dogs` (
  `dog_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
   ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`dog_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (dog_id)
PARTITIONS 10 */
```

Idealistic query for what I would like to achieve:

`from(i in dogs, select: i.dog_id, partition: "p1")`

The above doesn't work ofc, so 
I have achieved this with transforming the query to string with 
`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql` and editing it.

`... <> "PARTITION (#{partition}) AS" <> ...`

This feels hacky and it might break with future versions,
is there a way to achieve this with Ecto?